# usage of present perfect tense

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect, present-tense

My question is about the use of present perfect tense. To my knowledge this tense is used for the actions that have started in the past and continues up until now. I have questions about different cases for the same thing:

1. Lets assume that I went to another country for a vacation and I stayed there for a few days. Now today is my last day in that country and now I will return and I am calling a taxi and the receptionist in the hotel asks me how my trip was and I answer him: It's been lovely to be here or to stay here /It was lovely to be here or to stay here
2. I am in the airplane waiting to go back. Now another persons asks me the same question and which tense should I use?
3. I have returned and I arrived at my home country. For example my father asks me the same question and which tense should I use?

Comment: It's been lovely staying here. /  It's been lovely staying here. / It was lovely staying there.

Answer (score 0):

*1) Lets assume that I went to another country for a vacation and I stayed there for a few days. Now today is my last day in that country and now I will return and I am calling a taxi and the receptionist in the hotel asks me how my trip was and I answer him: It's been lovely to be here or to stay here /It was lovely to be here or to stay here*

"It's been lovely". If you're talking about your trip as a whole being lovely, I would just leave it at that and not include the 'to stay here' bit.
If you're saying that a particularly lovely part of your trip was the hotel, you could say "it's been lovely staying here"

Equally you could actually say "it was lovely"/"it was lovely staying here" - to me, both actually mean the same thing in this case

*2) I am in the airplane waiting to go back. Now another persons asks me the same question and which tense should I use?*

I would say that if you are still in the country, the same answer applies as above ("it was/has been lovely").

*3) I have returned and I arrived at my home country. for example my father asks me the same question and which tense should I use?*

Now the only appropriate tense becomes the simple past - "it was lovely"

Comment: Could we say that "It's been lovely" equals saying "I FEEL good about the whole experience" while "It was lovely" equals saying "The TIME of the trip was lovely, I will forever remember that wonderful things happened and all the lovely moments"?